# loop and submit form jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I have 2 form. When I submit frm1, i have some checked option and use variable checkedValues to store it.

I loop in each checked option, change value to frm2, submit it and open a popup after 3 second. But it not work with submit form 2 and setTimeout function.

Does anyone have any ideas to solve this?

```
<form  action="" method="post" name='frm1'>
    <input type="checkbox" name="1" id="1" value="1" class="checkbox">
    <input type="checkbox" name="2" id="2" value="1" class="checkbox">
    <input type="checkbox" name="3" id="3" value="0" class="checkbox">
    <input type="checkbox" name="4" id="4" value="0" class="checkbox">
    <input type="submit" value='add'>
</form>

<form action='http://example.com' method='post' name='frm2' target="_blank">
    <input type="text" name="fname" class="form-control" value=''>
    <input type="text" name="fvalue"class="form-control" value=''>
</form>

<script>
$('#add').click(function(){
    var store= <?php echo json_encode($store)?>;
    var checkedValues = $('input:checkbox:checked').map(function() {
            return this.id;
         }).get();

    $.each(checkedValues, function(index,val) {

        document.frm2.fname.value = store[val]['name'];
        document.frm2.fvalue.value = store[val]['value'];

        document.frm2.submit(); // not working

        setTimeout(function () {       // not working
             window.open("http://example.com/client, "_blank"), 3000);
         });
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Forms don't have values.  Inputs have values.  What are you trying to do here?  `document.frm2.value.value = store[val]['value'];`

Comment: Moreover, why don't you use `console.log()` and see what is happening on those first 2 assignments in your `$.each()` iteration?  Check the targets (to verify they are what you're intending to target) and the new values being assigned.

Comment: You're going to lose control as soon as your form is submitted. Open your popup before submitting the form.

Comment: hi  devlin carnate, Form2 don't have value, each time it loop in checkedValues, it get value from store array to fill to the form 2. The form have update two field, but It won't submit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is that your first form is being submitted, so your page gets reloaded and the second part of the script isn't executed. To prevent that you should use AJAX.

```
<input type="checkbox" name="1" id="1" value="1" class="checkbox">
<input type="checkbox" name="2" id="2" value="1" class="checkbox">
<input type="checkbox" name="3" id="3" value="0" class="checkbox">
<input type="checkbox" name="4" id="4" value="0" class="checkbox">
<button id="bt-add">add</button>

<form action='http://example.com' method='post' id="second-form" name='frm2' target="_blank">
    <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" value=''>
    <input type="text" name="value" class="form-control" value=''>
</form>

<script>
$('#bt-add').click(function(){
    var store= <?php echo json_encode($store)?>;
    var checkedValues = $('input:checkbox:checked').map(function() {
      return this.id;
    }).get();

    $.each(checkedValues, function(index,val) {
        $("#second-form").find("input[name='name']").val(store[val]['name']);
        $("#second-form").find("input[name='value']").val(store[val]['value']);

        $.ajax({
            url: "http://example.com",
            type:'GET',
            data: $("#second-form").serialize()
        });

    });

    setTimeout(function () {
      window.open("http://example.com/client", "_blank");
    }, 3000);
});

</script>
```

Fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/whb65L5w/8/).

Comment: Thanks for answer me. I try your way, but it not working too. the two input field update value, but the form won't sumit. And if i use window.open("http://example.com/client", "_blank"); without settimeout, it open pop up too. It mean the script clearly executed from the top to bottom, but for some reason, it not work like I expected.

Comment: @Thuclb What's happening?

Comment: @Thuclb I updated the code. See if it's working now.

Comment: Your solution are right. It work on jsfiddle.net. But I write my code on Zend 1x, and It still not working. May be I should try to find another problem to fix :))

Comment: @Thuclb Maybe it's some PHP related problem. What is the return of the `<?php echo json_encode($store)?>` expression?

Comment: I was tick in three box, and click add, but just one popup appear. Is it true?

Comment: ah, it's an array I got from database.

Comment: @Thuclb Yes, just one popup will appear. If you want one popup per item, put the `setTimeout` inside `$.each`.

Comment: I got it. Thanks for all :)